# Internal quasi-direct product of a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Weaken the requirement of two normal subgroups in an internal direct product and you get semidirect product. Even when both subgroups, say $H, K < G$ are not normal $G=HK$ if $H \cup K=G$ and $H \cap K={e}$.

1. Is there a standard notation for the latter? I'm thinking something like 'internal quasi-direct product'. What could be some general properties of $G$?
2. Let $H, K$ be subgroups of $G$ that are not normal in $G$ and $HK=KH$. It follows that $L=HK=KH$ is a group. Can $L$ be abelian?

Comment: (1) No standard notation, but it's called the knit product. This occurs "in nature" occasionally with a regular subgroup $H$ and point-stabilizer $K$ of a transitive(ly acting) group $G$. (2) Yes, easily, e.g. let $H=K$ be an abelian non-normal subgroup of a nonabelian group $G$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zappa%E2%80%93Sz%C3%A9p_product

Comment: Your condition on the union being all of $G$ is way too strong and would make everything uninteresting.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes, I'll have to replace it with HK=G and H \cap K={e}.